# List of Table names from SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to look for a way to get the list of all the table names used in various queries executed in a SQL Server database in last 30 days.

I have the queries and like to know if we can programmatically (rather than manually parsing it ) get the list of table names out of it or can get the details from any SQL Server system table.

Comment: This sounds like a *step* on the way towards solving some problem - can you tell us what that problem is?

Comment: How do you know that the queries you've collected are the full set of queries that have been executed in the last 30 days?

Comment: Yes- it is a step in solving one issue. We have a load process which loads all the tables in database (around 300 +), after this process is done - we run a job which uses about 60-70 tables.  Now rather than waiting for the whole load process to finish we will check these 60-70 tables and check if load is done in these table, then we will start job. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the server hasn't been restarted in the last 30 days, a potentially more accurate way to determine what tables have been queried (in the event that your collection of queries is incomplete):

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO

;WITH agg AS
(
    SELECT 
        [object_id],
        last_user_seek,
        last_user_scan,
        last_user_lookup,
        last_user_update
    FROM
        sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
    WHERE
        database_id = DB_ID()
)
SELECT
    [Schema] = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]),
    [Table_Or_View] = OBJECT_NAME([object_id]),
    last_read = MAX(last_read),
    last_write = MAX(last_write)
FROM
(
    SELECT [object_id], last_user_seek, NULL FROM agg
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [object_id], last_user_scan, NULL FROM agg
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [object_id], last_user_lookup, NULL FROM agg
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [object_id], NULL, last_user_update FROM agg
) AS x ([object_id], last_read, last_write)
GROUP BY
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]),
    OBJECT_NAME([object_id])
ORDER BY [Schema],[Table_Or_View];
```

If you want to rely on the queries you've collected, there is no magic system table that maps queries to table(s). So, not sure exactly where are how these queries you've collected are stored, but you could attempt to parse the table or index names out of the plan XML using `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` and `sys.dm_exec_sql_text`. This will not be simple and, unless you have more memory than you could possibly need, it is highly unlikely that all of the plans for 30 days worth of queries are currently in the plan cache.

Comment: Is it possible to tie this result to the actual query executed in the database?

Comment: This result just grabs aggregates. An index scan, for example, from two different queries, each just count as 1 scan. So no, there is no way to tie this to specific queries. If that's really what you want to do, you're going to have to parse. Why don't you just have your load process update some log table when it's done loading a specific table, then you don't have to go checking query stats or other DMVs and certainly not parsing query text.

Comment: Load process will update log table but we are in a process to find out that 60-70 table used in next job. This job is combination of direct queries and stored procedure and difficult to parse manually. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also if users add more queries or new workflows/ procedures etc, we should be able to repeat this task without any manual parsing.

Comment: @Amit other than what I've already suggested? No, not really.